# Why is malloc allocated array shows less size than static allocated array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, sizeof

Why is `arr1` size less than `arr2`, am I missing something? Does it have to do something with malloc and stack, heap?

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int length = 4;
    int *arr1 = (int*)malloc(length*sizeof(int));

    int arr2[length];
    arr2[0] = 10;
    arr2[1] = 20;
    arr2[2] = 30;
    arr2[3] = 40;

    arr1 = arr2;

    for (int i = 0; i<length; printf("%d\n", arr1[i++])) ;

    printf("Size of arr %lu\n", sizeof(arr1));
    printf("Size of arr2 %lu\n", sizeof(arr2));
    printf("Size of int %lu", sizeof(int));    
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -g new.cpp && ./a.out
10
20
30
40
Size of arr 8
Size of arr2 16
Size of int 4
```

I was expecting to have `arr1` and `arr2` both have 16 byte size.

Comment: `arr1` is a pointer. `arr2` is an array. Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays. Arrays can decay to pointers but that doesnt make then the same.

Comment: `int arr2[length]` isn't standard c++. Some compiler allow it as an extension. Always enable all warnings.

Comment: BTW: what do you expect `arr1 = arr2;` does? Hint: it probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: `sizeof(arr1)` is telling you the size of the pointer variable, not the allocated memory. There is no way to persuade `sizeof` to tell you the size of a `malloc`-allocated block.

Comment: OT: hint: don't write "clever" code like this: `for (int i = 0; i<length; printf("%d\n", arr1[i++])) ;`. It's difficult to read. Write readable and understandable code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `arr1` declared like

```
 int *arr1 = (int*)malloc(length*sizeof(int));
```

has the pointer type `int *` while the variable `arr2` declared as a variable length array

```
int arr2[length];
```

has the type `int[4]`.

So the expression `sizeof( arr1 )` that is equivalent to `sizeof( int * )` yields the size of the pointer itself.

Pay attention to that your program has a memory leak because a memory was allocated and its address was stored in the pointer `arr1` and then the pointer `arr1` was reassigned

```
arr1 = arr2;
```

The array `arr2` used as an expression in the above assignment statement is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. That is the above statement in fact is equivalent to

```
arr1 = &arr[0];
```

Also to output a value of the type `size_t` you should use conversion specification `%zu` because the C Standard accepts that it is not necessary that the type `unsigned long` is an alias for the type `size_t`..

From the C Standard (7.19 Common definitions <stddef.h>)

> 4 The types used for size_t and ptrdiff_t should not have an integer
> conversion rank greater than that of signed long int **unless the
> implementation supports objects large enough to make this necessary**

Also if you wil write for example `sizeof( arr2 + 0 )`  then again the expression will yield the size of a pointer because in this expression `arr2 + 0` with the pointer arithmetic the array `arr2` is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

Answer (score 3):

First things first `int arr2[length]` is not standard C++. Some compilers allow it as an extension.

---

Now coming to the question, `arr1` is a pointer to an int(an `int*`) while `arr2` is a array of type int(int [4]). This means that:

`sizeof(arr1)` gives you the **number of bytes the pointer `arr1` occupies** while `sizeof(arr2)` gives you the **number of bytes the array occupies**. *In your case* an `int` is occupying 4 bytes and so the array occupies 16 bytes. OTOH, in your case, `int*` is occupying 8 bytes.

```
sizeof(arr1) //same as sizeof(int*)
sizeof(arr2) //same as sizeof(int [4])
```

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(arr1)` is the same as `sizeof(int*)` while `sizeof(arr2)` is the same as `sizeof(int[4])`.

In other words, `arr1` is a pointer to `int`, while `arr2` is an array of 4 `int`s. They are of different type and those types occupy different amount of bytes.

`arr1` does point to the first element of an array, but that does not make it an array. The actual size of the two arrays in your program is the same.