# How do I pass a string to a function requiring BYTE*?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, null-terminated

I've copied the entirety of this code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/example-c-program--creating-an-hmac

I turned it into a function that accepts two strings. I would like these strings to be in place of Data1 and Data2.

```
BYTE        Data1[]     = {0x70,0x61,0x73,0x73,0x77,0x6F,0x72,0x64};
BYTE        Data2[]     = {0x6D,0x65,0x73,0x73,0x61,0x67,0x65};
```

I've tried everything I've found online up until this point and the function does not print the same hash. How do I use strings to replace these values? More relevant code below.

```
if (!CryptHashData(
    hHash,                    // handle of the hash object
    Data1,                    // password to hash
    sizeof(Data1),            // number of bytes of data to add
    0))                       // flags
{
   printf("Error in CryptHashData 0x%08x \n", 
          GetLastError());
   goto ErrorExit;
}

...

if (!CryptHashData(
    hHmacHash,                // handle of the HMAC hash object
    Data2,                    // message to hash
    sizeof(Data2),            // number of bytes of data to add
    0))                       // flags
{
   printf("Error in CryptHashData 0x%08x \n", 
          GetLastError());
   goto ErrorExit;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(test3Array)` is the size of the pointer and has nothing to do with the size of the array it points to.  I'm sure there's a duplicate for this.

Comment: Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59150444/result-of-sizeof-for-c-arrays-and-pointers though it's kind of the other way around.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-size-of-an-array-from-a-pointer-pointing-to-the-first-element-a looks to be the highest voted.

Comment: As to your last sentence, what do you mean by "convert"?  What's your goal?

Comment: "What's your goal?" is very important here. Typically you simply use the backing buffer of a `std::string` itself when you need a `char` array version. No conversion required. If you need a non-`const` string you can use `data` in place of `c_str`, But if your compiler is too out-of-date to provide `data`, `&test3[0]` works on all but the most bizarre of `std::string` implementations. If you need to "convert" a `string` to an array, odds are really good you're headed in a bad direction.

Comment: See the explanation given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77873067/12002570)

Comment: @user4581301 I need to convert it because that is what the function requires. I just took code from a Microsoft page called "Example C Program: Creating an HMAC"  The data in the example is a byte array, but I want it to be a string because it's literally a password. I spent HOURS searching. I don't know how to get the proper array length 7 from the string "message" so the function gives me a different hash than the example.

Comment: @Andrew A `std::string` contains a buffer of characters, you can access that buffer using the `data` method which returns a pointer to the buffer. There is no need to convert (this is a very common newbie misunderstanding). So just use `test3.data()` and `test3.size()` to pass to the other routine. You might need to cast the pointer returned by `test3.data()` but otherwise no conversion is necessary.

Comment: Question back why do you even still use "C" style arrays. Use `std::array `and `std::vector` (gets rid of all that stupid pointer decay issues as well). There is hardly ever any need in C++ to have to use sizeof (the only place I still use it is in template meta programming)

Comment: @PepijnKramer The function I need to use takes a native array of bytes. No matter what type I use, I ultimately have to convert "message" to a byte array of length 7.

Comment: @Andrew if the function doesn't modify the data, you don't need to convert it to a byte array

Comment: @M.M Well the compiler didn't like anything I passed, so I did a search for converting string to byte array and found like four different ways and none of them resulted in the same hash as the example code. When I looped through the byte array and compared it to the original, it had one extra element while the 8-letter word did not.

Comment: @Andrew You don't need to convert to a byte array, as said by myself and others, this is a common misunderstanding. If the compiler didn't like anything you tried then you just made a mistake somewhere, so need to post that code, not the conversion code. As I said you need the `data` method for the pointer and the `size` method for the size of your password.

Comment: @Andrew Programming is hard, everyone knows that, but newbies have it extra hard because they sometimes create additional complexity where it is not needed. Trying to convert a string to a byte array so you can use a function which takes a byte array is an example of that.

Comment: @Andrew -- *I need to convert it because that is what the function requires* -- A `BYTE` in Windows world is a typedef for `unsigned char`.  A `std::string` stores an array of `char`, which can be reinterpreted as an array of `unsigned char`.  So there is no need for any conversion -- [see this](https://godbolt.org/z/sjG89YE9c).

Comment: With std::array<std::uint8_t,N> values, you can still use `values.data()` to get a pointer to the first element (which you can use in legacy api calls). But you still get all the C++ benefits from lifecycle rules for objects including being able to return an array from a function directly (which is a PAIN with "C" style arrays because the only option  for that is a raw non-owning pointer, something definitely no longer recommended in C++)

Comment: @john Please don't call me or anybody on this site a newbie. It's unkind and I'm not a newbie, I just don't write in C++ because it's a terrible, terrible language that's the cause of an overwhelming majority of security flaws.

Comment: @Andrew No offence is intended. Maybe you are not a newbie in general, but you are a newbie at C++, that's all I meant.

Comment: @john Your solution to use .data() and .size() works. I've edited my question so it's closer to the actual solution I was looking for. I thought I was being helpful by simplifying it, since the solutions I found _on this website_ suggested solutions that resulted in the wrong length arrays. Hopefully it gets opened so you can answer it because the linked questions are not directly helpful.

Comment: @Andrew OK done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `data` and `size` methods of `std::string` can be used to get a pointer to and size of the char array managed by the string.

These methods can be used to pass the string data to a C function that is expecting pointer and size of data parameters.

Using the example above this would look something like this

```
string str = ...;
if (!CryptHashData(
    hHash,                    // handle of the hash object
    (BYTE*)str.data(),                    // password to hash
    str.size(),            // number of bytes of data to add
    0))
```

Note that `data` returns `char*`, in this case a cast is necessary to convert the pointer to `BYTE*`. Also note that `size` returns the array length in characters not bytes, but for a `std::string` these are the same.